# Index_not_found_exception no such index found in elasticsearch using Powershell

Tags: java, json, powershell, curl, jdbc

I have created two files that are,

1. jdbc_sqlserver.json:

   ```
   {
       "type": "jdbc",
       "jdbc": {
           "url": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=merchant2merchant;integratedSecurity=true;",
           "user": "",
           "password": "",
           "sql": "select * from planets",
           "treat_binary_as_string": true,
           "elasticsearch": {
               "cluster": "elasticsearch",
               "host": "localhost",
               "port": 9200
           },
           "index": "testing"
       }
   }
   ```
2. jdb_sqlserver.ps1:

   ```
   function Get - PSVersion {
       if (test - path variable: psversiontable) {
           $psversiontable.psversion
       } else {
           [version]
           "1.0.0.0"
       }
   }

   $powershell = Get - PSVersion
   if ($powershell.Major - le 2) {
       Write - Error "Oh, so sorry, this script requires Powershell 3 
           (due to convertto - json)
       "
       exit
   }
   if ((Test - Path env: \JAVA_HOME) - eq $false) {
       Write - Error "Environment variable JAVA_HOME must be set to your java    home"
       exit
   }
   curl - XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/users/"

   $DIR = "C:\Program Files\elasticsearch\plugins\elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0-     dist\elasticsearch-jdbc-2.3.4.0\"
   $FEEDER_CLASSPATH = "$DIR\lib"
   $FEEDER_LOGGER = "file://$DIR\bin\log4j2.xml"

   java - cp "$FEEDER_CLASSPATH\*" - "Dlog4j.configurationFile=$FEEDER_LOGGER"
   "org.xbib.tools.Runner"
   "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
   jdbc_sqlserver.json
   ```

and running the second one in Powershell using command `.\jdb_sqlserver.ps1` in "C:\servers\elasticsearch\bin\feeder" path but I got error *likwIndex_not_found_exception* no such index found in powershell.

Comment: It's ElasticSearch's way of telling you that the `testing` index doesn't exist on the `elasticsearch` cluster

Comment: could you  please tell how to correct it i don't have much experience in  elasticsearch recently trying to learn it...